# Is set $\{A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} : \text{tr}(A) = 0\}$ is bounded and closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

$$\{A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} : \text{tr}(A) = 0\}$$
Inner product is defined to be  <$A, B$>$ = \text{tr}(A^TB) $
I was asked if the set
$$D = s \subset   \text{Mat}_{2×2}$$
is closed and bounded.
I showed that $D^c$ is open hence $D$ closed (is it correct?).
how do I show It's (not) bounded?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** What is the norm of $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & n \\ n& 0\end{bmatrix}$$?